# adb no longer starts up if connected to Pulse VPN

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, pulse

Since Android Studio updated to Bumblebee 2021.1.1 (January 19, 2022 build), when I start Android Studio I get an error along the lines of

> Error initializing ADB: Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start
> adb server: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037 could not
> read ok from ADB Server * failed to start daemon error: cannot connect
> to daemon
>
> adb.exe start-server failed

If I go to a command line and type "adb start-server" I get

> error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): connection reset

The odd thing is, if I disconnect from Pulse VPN, I have 0 issues. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this.  Quite literally the instant I disconnect, the Device File Explorer switches to showing me the file system on the device.

Comment: I've seen this error since Bumblebee; but I don't use Pulse VPN; and `adb start-server` works for me; try to run it from cmd as an administrator.. My issue is that I have to do that every time I run AS

Comment: I can't run start-server while connected to VPN, but as soon as I disconnect I can.  I suspect it's some sort of proxy, or other firewall type of mechanism that Pulse uses

Comment: Just notified with a [patch](https://developer.android.com/studio?utm_source=android-studio) hopefully fix it

Comment: I don't think it is related to Bumblebee because adb is part of the platform-tool package not of Android Studio. But a short time after Bumblebee platform-tools v32 were released and there are a few question here on SO regarding problems. So if you can go back to v31.

Comment: Try to disable this option `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging`